# Why does the Chrome console show the array in different ways?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I wrote a piece of code like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script>
        var arr = [1, 45, 37, 5, 48, 15, 37, 26, 29, 2, 46, 4, 17, 50, 52];
        console.log(arr);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I found a weird thing, if I open this file in the browser then F12 to call the console, the array is simplified. And if you refresh this page, the console shows the detail of this array.

[image]

And if I input the url with the devtool on, it also shows the detail.

Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

It's simply done for performance reasons. If the console is closed, there is no sense displaying the entire array out (Which would require chrome to read the array and output it).

If the chrome devtools are open, performance is no longer an issue, because you're actually looking at the console (Which 99% of users wont do).

Comment: Thanks a lot for both the answer and the modification of my poor English. I kind of want to read the source code now.

Comment: @Arjenloeb For the record, you approved an edit which added additional spelling errors to your post. I've gone ahead and reverted it back to the previous revision.